# Why doesn't the obvious use of `std::shared_ptr<T[]>` work?

Tags: c++, c++17, shared-ptr

Seems like the obvious use of `std::shared_ptr<T[]>` (added with C++ 17) is to hold a pointer to `T`, and use `delete[]` when it's time to destroy the managed object. But this code:

```
#include <memory>

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<int[]> sp(new int[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

doesn't compile with any of the online compilers I've tried. In all cases, the error message is a variant of this:

> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:3759:18:
>   note: candidate template ignored:
>         requirement 'is_convertible<int *, int (*)[]>::value' was not satisfied [with _Yp = int]
>           explicit shared_ptr(_Yp* __p,

that is, the constructor that takes a pointer gets SFINAED out because the pointer to the element type isn't convertible to a pointer to array. That seems to be required in the C++ 17 standard and in C++ 20.

Is that really what's intended? How can I use that constructor? Or, alternatively, how do I create a `std::shared_ptr` object that correctly manages an array without explicitly specifying a deleter?

Comment: [norepro](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MTDBCwh5IXV8CwmD). Update your compiler.

Comment: @SombreroChicken -- try it with clang.

Comment: @PeteBecker: "*Seems like the obvious use of std::shared_ptr<T[]> (added with C++ 17) is to hold a pointer to T,*" No, the obvious (and only) use is to hold an *array* of `T`, which is why it is `T[]`, not `T`. Which is why you gave it the results of `new int[3]` rather than `new int`.

Comment: @NicolBolas -- try the link from Sombrero Chicken and change the compiler to Clang.

Comment: @NicolBolas -- and there's something wrong with my installation of Clang and with my installation of g++? No, it's not that simple.  Formally, the error message is correct: that requirement comes directly from the C++17 standard.

Comment: @NicolBolas -- the type returned by `new int[3]` is `int*`, just like `new int`.

Comment: @PeteBecker Both [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) and [the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/util.smartptr.shared#const-8) say that desired overload of the constructor should apply with `U = Y = int`, `T = U[] = int[]`, as `Y` is complete and `Y(*)[] = int(*)[]` is convertible to `T* = int(*)[]`. I vote library bug.

Comment: Digging in: GNU's `libstdc++` [correctly implements](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/shared_ptr_base.h#L973-L993) the complicated logic needed for this to work. LLVM's `libc++` [uses `is_convertible` directly](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/memory#L3669-L3671), which is not good enough. I'm very surprised no one's noticed this before, though...

Comment: @HTNW — thanks for the research. I’ll look at this tomorrow.

Comment: @HTNW I guess that tells us how much of a use case there is for this functionality

Comment: Filed [llvm #44592](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=44592).

Comment: Use [`std::make_shared`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared). Using `new` directly could lead to memory leaks in case constructors throw. `std::make_shared<int[]>(3)`

Comment: As for alternatives, `std::make_shared<int[]>(size_t)` can replace the construction if you are fine with having it allocate the array for you.

Comment: @PeteBecker Of course not but if you use a class that has a throwing constructor then it could

Comment: @Kerndog73 — no, if the constructor throws an exception `new` will clean up he memory.

Comment: I get a different result using clang 10.0.1 on https://wandbox.org/ and on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/1EsfYWbTK). It fails on wandbox but compiles on godbolt.

Answer (score 2):

Your program is valid and it should work. The `error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::shared_ptr<int []>'` was only in Clang with its `libc++` standard library implementation till the version 10, and it was fixed in version 11. [Resolved bug](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/43937).

Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WdbdTTPPj